# Cryptographic failure while signing assembly in Visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dll

I don't know where I went wrong. When I build it searches for the default path for the DLL to sign in. Eventhough I specified the path.

I have created and stored my .snk file in the same location as the DLL.

```
//Assembly info file for errorcollection

using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

// General Information about an assembly is controlled through the following 
// set of attributes. Change these attribute values to modify the information
// associated with an assembly.
[assembly: AssemblyTitle("ErrorCollection")]
[assembly: AssemblyDescription("")]
[assembly: AssemblyConfiguration("")]
[assembly: AssemblyCompany("")]
[assembly: AssemblyProduct("ErrorCollection")]
[assembly: AssemblyCopyright("Copyright ©  2010")]
[assembly: AssemblyTrademark("")]
[assembly: AssemblyCulture("")]

// Setting ComVisible to false makes the types in this assembly not visible 
// to COM components.  If you need to access a type in this assembly from 
// COM, set the ComVisible attribute to true on that type.
[assembly: ComVisible(false)]

// The following GUID is for the ID of the typelib if this project is exposed to COM
[assembly: Guid("2c17131b-0ae3-4146-a797-308f5958e819")]

// Version information for an assembly consists of the following four values:
//
//      Major Version
//      Minor Version 
//      Build Number
//      Revision
//
// You can specify all the values or you can default the Build and Revision Numbers 
// by using the '*' as shown below:
// [assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.*")]
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.0.0")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.0.0")]
[assembly: System.Reflection.AssemblyKeyFile(@"D:\Services\bin\ErrorCollection.snk")]
```

I get the following error:

> "Cryptographic failure while signing assembly 'D:\Services\ErrorCollection\obj\Debug\ErrorCollection.dll' -- 'Error reading key file 'D:\Services\bin\ErrorCollection.snk' -- The system cannot find the file specified. '    ErrorCollection"

Comment: Is the snk actually in D:\Services\bin\ErrorCollection.snk ?

Comment: yes i seen it. its located exactly where i specified.

Comment: Is there an explanation as to why this question was closed? So that I get an idea as to what not to post.

Answer (score 10):

Check the access rights to the Keys folder on the local machine and give permissions to the VS user.

```
C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys
```

Comment: I had the same issue and solved it in a similar manner see https://github.com/nosami/Omnisharp/issues/150

Comment: Perfect conclusion. I've changed the owner to local group Administrators of that folder and forgot to add permissions to them.

Answer (score 8):

For me this problem happened after upgrading to windows 10.
The location of the MachineKeys is then located at a different location namely

C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA

RightClick the MachineKeys and make sure all privileges are set.

Comment: For future readers....this answer solved my issue.  BUT I also ran into a "granting permissions" issue....as seen by this url.  https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/db04b57c-7684-4e52-8e1a-5e4407f6e2ab/windows-2012-failed-to-enumerate-objects-in-the-container-access-denied?forum=winserver8gen

Comment: you may not get that granting-permissions issue.  but if you do, follow the url in my previous comment OR internet-search for the phrase "Failed to enumerate objects in the container. Access denied"         but after i got past the issue of actually granting permissions...this answer saved the day.

Answer (score 2):

The path must be relative to the assembly.

Please check out the following knowledge [base](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/328379) .

Hence try changing

@"D:\Services\bin\ErrorCollection.snk"

to be something like (here I am assuming it is four levels up to your root d drive)

@"..\..\..\..\Services\bin\ErrorCollection.snk"

Answer (score 1):

Try creating  new snk with the same name and overwriting the old one

This worked for me. Guessing the snk got corrupted somehow

Answer (score 1):

Right click on your Project-->Properties-->Check "Sign the assembly"

Answer (score 1):

What fixed it for me was to make sure I was running Visual Studio as Administrator.

Answer (score 0):

you can also just deactivate signing in your visualstudio

Answer (score 0):

Open Visual Studio with Run as Administrator, resolved my issue.